# Pivot / Unpivot the following data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to Pivots so I'm not exactly sure how I would need to do this.

I have the following data:

[image: Budgets]

I need to pivot/unpivot the above data.

I need the following Columns:

1. GLLink
2. AccType
3. Budget
4. Budget Value

---

I've tried developing the code, but I'm afraid I am doing it completely wrong:

```
select
*
from
(
select
*
from    Budgets
)   x
unpivot
(
GLLink for Budget in ([AccType])
)   p
order by GLLink, Budget
```

---

The results I would require should look like this:

[image]

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the data you showed us are in a table named 'yourtable', here is the `cross apply` way:

```
select t.GLLink,t.Acctype,u.*
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
    values 
    ('Budget01',Budget01),
    ('Budget02',Budget02),
    ('Budget03',Budget03),
    ('Budget04',Budget04),
    ('Budget05',Budget05),
    ('Budget06',Budget06),
    ('Budget07',Budget07)
)u(Budget,[Budget Value])
```

The way it works: `cross apply` "sees" one row each time. For this row, it uses the `values()` operator to create a table, so we make the pairs as you need them. In the end, we give a name to this table (u for unpivoted), and also name the columns.

Converting columns to rows is unpivoting (what you need), pivoting is the reverse.

Comment: Thank you George, I think this would work, however I should have mentioned in my question that I have exactly 60 Budget Columns, i.e. `Budget01, Budget02.....Budget59, Budget60`. How would I go about altering your answer for the 60 columns? Should I just add the values in under `Budget07` as per your answer?

Comment: Yes. Shouldn't be too hard with a text editor - except if you prefer to actually make it dynamic sql. The one alternative I know is the `UNPIVOT` operator, dont remember for sure if it would save you the hassle.

Comment: Do you mind posting an answer for that as well? I would like to learn from it... :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, I prefer cross apply too much to use the unpivot operator. You will find multiple threads here in SO or you can visit the MS site about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot

Comment: Nice answer, I agree this is clearer than UNPIVOT. To get up to those 60 columns I tend to save myself some typing and use Excel to generate the rows of text to go underneath values.

Comment: @BarneyL, I agree, that's what I did in Excel :-D